# ImageMagickで「自動改行した長いテキストを追加した画像」を出力したい。テキスト部分の背景を透明指定する方法が分からない

Tags: imagemagick

最終的にやりたいこと
ImageMagickで「自動改行した長いテキストを追加した画像」を出力したい

具体的には
1.600px × 600px の元画像を読み込む
2.上記画像に合わせて自動改行した長いテキストを、上記画像の上に合成
3.画像出力

---

目的に近い形(背景lightblue)で期待した通り動作するコード

```
convert originImg.jpg -background lightblue -fill blue -font hogeFont.otf -pointsize 36 \
          -size 320px   caption:'ものすごく長いテキスト.' -gravity south -composite output.jpg
```

---

背景を透明指定したいのですが、期待した通り動作しないコード
矩形が白色で出力されてしまう

background指定しない

```
convert originImg.jpg -fill white -font hogeFont.otf -pointsize 36 \
          -size 320px   caption:'ものすごく長いテキスト.' -gravity south -composite output.jpg
```

αを0%

```
convert originImg.jpg -background gray(0%) -fill white -font hogeFont.otf -pointsize 36 \
          -size 320px   caption:'ものすごく長いテキスト.' -gravity south -composite output.jpg
```

rgbaで指定

```
convert originImg.jpg -background rgba(0,0,0,0) -fill white -font hogeFont.otf -pointsize 36 \
          -size 320px   caption:'ものすごく長いテキスト.' -gravity south -composite output.jpg
```

-transparentで指定

```
convert originImg.jpg transparent white -fill white -font hogeFont.otf -pointsize 36 \
          -size 320px   caption:'ものすごく長いテキスト.' -gravity south -composite output.jpg
```

[Caption - Word Wrapped Label](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/)

Comment: `-background none` にしてみてはどうでしょうか。手元の ImageMagick のバージョンは `ImageMagick 6.9.11-60 Q16` ですが、これで背景を透明にできました。

Comment: 「background none:」を試したら、期待通り動作しました。